# Alaska and Hawaii not formatting correctly for County Choropleth Map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, choropleth, choroplethr

I am trying to format a Choropleth Map of the United States to a specific color and unfortunately, when using `scale_fill_brewer` to change the color; only 48 of the states do (Hawaii and Alaska do not). Is it possible to know if I can implement the coloring to Hawaii and Alaska as well?

```
library(choroplethr) 
library(choroplethrMaps)
library(ggplot2) 
data(df_pop_county)

county_choropleth(df_pop_county, title = "Title1", legend = "Top 20% of Index", num_colors = 9) + 

geom_polygon(aes(fill=value), color="white")  + 

scale_fill_brewer(name="Top Index", palette="YlOrRd")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use this option and have it properly update all states we can [work with it as an R6 object](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/vignettes/c-county-choropleth.html) as follows:

```
library(choroplethr) 
library(choroplethrMaps)
library(ggplot2) 
data(df_pop_county)

choro              = CountyChoropleth$new(df_pop_county)
choro$title        = "2012 Population Estimates"
choro$ggplot_scale = scale_fill_brewer(name="Population", palette=2, drop=FALSE)
choro$render()
```

[image]

Using the particular pallet you mentioned:

```
choro              = CountyChoropleth$new(df_pop_county)
choro$title        = "2012 Population Estimates"
choro$ggplot_scale = scale_fill_brewer(name="Population", palette="YlOrRd", drop=FALSE)
choro$render()
```

[image]