# Alaska and Hawaii not formatting correctly for Choropleth Map in R using ChoroplethrZip

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, choropleth

I am trying to create choropleth map based on zipcodes using the choroplethrZip package. My question is related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938565/alaska-and-hawaii-not-formatting-correctly-for-county-choropleth-map-in-r/42752869?noredirect=1#comment72621975_42752869). I am having the same problem, where Alaska and Hawaii are not updated if I change colormap using the scale_fill_brewer.

My data is a simple dataframe with two columns, something like this.

```
region value
1  00501  1052
2  00544   635
3  00601   717
4  00602   264
5  00603  1275
6  00604     4
```

If I create my choropleth with the default function call.

```
zip_choropleth(df_sample,
           title="Sample Cases",
           legend="Cases")
```

[Here is what I get][2]

When I change the fill using the scale_fill_brewer, all the map is changed, expect Alaska and Hawaii, here is the code:

```
zip_choropleth(df_sample,
           title="Sample Cases",
           legend="Cases") + scale_fill_brewer(type="seq"
                ,palette="RdPu"
                , direction = 1)
```

[Here is the new choropleth with Alaska and Hawaii unchanged.][3]

First, you can see what is happening. Also, the statelines are not drawn, I would like to add them if possible. When I tried to use the example in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938565/alaska-and-hawaii-not-formatting-correctly-for-county-choropleth-map-in-r/42752869?noredirect=1#comment72621975_42752869). 
Here is what I get.

```
choro              = zip_choropleth$new(df_sample)
```

Gives the following error: `Error in zip_choropleth$new : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`.

Now, I am shooting in the dark, so I tried another way:

```
choro              = zip_choropleth(df_sample)
choro$title        = "Sample Cases"
choro$ggplot_scale = scale_fill_brewer(name="Cases", palette="RdPu",  drop=FALSE)
choro$render()
```

The last command creates a error `Error: attempt to apply non-function`.

I am not sure if this clarifies the problem. 
Hope you can help.

Here is the solution:

```
choro              = ZipChoropleth$new(df_sample)
choro$title        = "Sample Cases"
choro$ggplot_scale = scale_fill_brewer(name="Cases", palette="RdPu", drop=FALSE)
choro$render()
```

This updates Alaska and Hawaii with the new palette, but changes the lines of the zipcode areas and messes the drawing. At least I go the first problem taken care of. 
[Alaska and Hawaii updated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYi0x.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alaska and Hawaii not formatting correctly for County Choropleth Map in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938565/alaska-and-hawaii-not-formatting-correctly-for-county-choropleth-map-in-r)

Comment: Thanks Mike. They are different. I tried to treat the zip_chorpleth function from the ChoroplethZip package the same as suggested in the answer, but it is no the same.

Comment: What is different?  You are going to have to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want help.